# Validating two different structures with same name

Tags: xml, schema, xerces, xsd-1.1

I have an element, say **Car**, that have multiple nested elements (i.e. **Body**, **Color**, etc). There can be many different kind of cars, but they will all be represented with the element **Car**; however, the elements in **Body**, **Color** can differ.

For example, I have these two xml:

Car1.xml

```xml
<Car>
    <Body>
        <Length>2</Length>
        <Shape>Box</Shape>
    </Body>
    <Color>
        <PrimColor>Red</PrimColor>
        <SecColor>
            <Hue>Blue</Hue>
        </SecColor>
    </Color>
</Car>
```

Car2.xml

```xml
<Car>
    <Body>
        <Length>2</Length>
        <Shape>Box</Shape>
        <Sunroof>True</Sunroof>
    </Body>
    <Color>
        <PrimColor>Red</PrimColor>
        <SecColor>
            <Gloss>True</Gloss>
            <Tinted>False</Tinted>
        </SecColor>
    </Color>
</Car>
```

I need create an xsd to validate both of those with the following conditions

- If the Body element does not contain the element `Sunroof`, the element `SecColor` can only contain the element `Hue`, but it is not required to be there
- If the Body element contains `Sunroof`, the element `SecColor` can only contain `Gloss` and `Tinted`, but they are not required to be there (one, both or none can appear)

I cannot change the xml (it is given to me).

Currently, I just set `minOccurs="0"` for those special elements, but that does not enforce the rule above.

I looked into choice groups, but xerces complains with "Multiple elements with name 'Body', with different types, appear in the model group." This was what I tried to do

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="Cars" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="Car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Body">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer" />
                                    <xs:element name="Shape" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Color">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="PrimColor" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="SecColor" >
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="Hue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Body">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer" />
                                    <xs:element name="Shape" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="Sunroof" type="xs:boolean" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Color">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="PrimColor" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="SecColor" >
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="Gloss" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                                <xs:element name="Tinted" type="xs:boolean"  minOccurs="0" />
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I thought about the Conditional Types, but they only work on attributes and the xml does not contain any.

Is it possible to enforce these rules and validate the xml using xsd 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using assert to validate my xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="Cars" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="Car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Body">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer" />
                            <xs:element name="Shape" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Sunroof" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Color">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="PrimColor" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="SecColor" >
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Hue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Gloss" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="Tinted" type="xs:boolean"  minOccurs="0" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="
                (not(Car/Body/Sunroof) and 
                not(Car/Color/SecColor/Gloss) and
                not(Car/Color/SecColor/Tinted))
                or
                (count(Car/Body/Sunroof) eq 1 and 
                not(Car/Color/SecColor/Hue))" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is ensure that if Sunroof does not exists, the Gloss and Tinted element cannot also; likewise, if Sunroof exists, the element Hue cannot.